# Period apply in xts - column max

Tags: r, statistics, xts, zoo

Is there any funktion like colMeans to get the maximum of the day e.g. colMax?

```
period.apply(df.xts, endpoints(df.xts, "days", 1), colMeans)
```

Or are there any other solutions?
Thanks

Comment: No, but you could use `function(x) apply(x,2,max)`.

Comment: Thx! There is one in `matrixStats` but not working with xts;-)